# react-dates: disabling the default calendar popup

Tags: react-dates

[`ReactDateRangePicker`](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates), gives it's own date picker to use:
[image]

I actually want this field only and do not want the default calendar date range picker, I have my own date picker that I'd like to place using custom css positioning when the focus changes. How do I disable this default calendar popup?

Answer (score 0):

well, there seems to be a css workaround by overriding these classes:

```
.DateRangePicker_picker {
    display:none !important;
}

.DateInput_fang{
    display: none !important;
}
```